# Keep alive the object for using them in another program in python

Tags: python, object, python-3.x, word2vec

I am using word2vec to calculate similarity between two words. So for the model I am using GoogleNews.
This model is quite huge and hence takes lot of time to load.

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('D:/Userfiles/vsachidananda/Downloads/GoogleNews-vectors negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

I would like to load this and keep in a variable/object so that whenever I run a python program I should be able to call just

```
model.similarity('word1','word2')
```

How can this be achieved? Any idea?

Comment: I guess that pickling the model with model.save() then loading it is even slower ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to share complex objects between Python processes is to use `multiprocessing.Manager`.
But `model` would be **pickled** and **unpickled** each time it needs to be shared with a subprocess. I guess it would be as slow as `load_word2vec_format`.

You could instead run a launcher that loads `model` once, then waits and executes another python script on demand. A very simple launcher would look like this:

```
import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(...)

try:
    import traceback
    import script

    while True:
        raw_input()

        try:
            reload(script)
            script.main(model)
        except:
            print traceback.print_exc()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'exit launcher'
```

With this basic launcher, `script.py` should be in the same folder and need to define a `main()`:

```
def main(model):
    model.similarity('word1','word2')
    ...
```

Comment: As you said, model.save/load is as slow as load_word2vec_format. Due to large model size, even pickling takes loads of time and sometimes crashes with Memory error. I will try the launcher you suggested above....